# How to Allow CGI in HTML to accept Whitespace as Parameter

Tags: html, perl, cgi

Currently I have a link like follows:

```
<a href=/myweb/cgi-bin/my.cgi?name=B. anthracis>B. anthracis</a>
```

But instead of taking **B. anthracis** as input parameter, it takes **B.** instead.
How can I modify the above HTML or CGI script to allow that?

And currently my CGI script looks like this:

```
use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new();
my $param = $cgi->param('name');
print "$param\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should URL encode the query string:

```
<a href="/myweb/cgi-bin/my.cgi?name=B.%20anthracis">B. anthracis</a>
```

And including the quotes on your attributes is strongly recommended.

You can use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in JavaScript or [`uri_escape`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aEscape) in Perl to encode each parameter name and value before building the query string.